# Registration does not work - empty form returned

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

we have a multi-shop setup CE 1.8.1, with 2 themes on 2 different domains showing the exact same products.

Now suddenly our one theme does no longer allow users to register. I have upgraded the theme (adding the form_key and changing the submit link in add to cart form etc ..), but now users can no longer register via this one theme (url).

When you hit submit, the blank form is simply reloaded.

I've compared the 2 submit commands and parameters which are bieng submitted, and they compare from the one store to the other, and they are identical, but in one theme it registers the new customer, in the other it fails without an error.

Here the one that does not work:

```
/customer/account/createpost/?confirmation=testtest&day=&dob=&email=test%40test.de&error_url=&firstname=test&gender=&lastname=test&month=&password=testtest&prefix=Frau&success_url=&year=
```

Here the one that does work:

```
/customer/account/createpost/?confirmation=testtest&day=&dob=&email=test%40test.de&error_url=&firstname=test&gender=&lastname=test&month=&password=testtest&prefix=Herr&success_url=&year=
```

Even in the logs there is nothing - i have logging enabled.

For any help I would be greatly appreciative.

---

**Edit:**

Ok. i've editedt AccountController.php and added the following into the createPostAction() function:

```
    Zend_Debug::dump($this->getRequest()->isPost());
    Mage::log($this->getRequest()->isPost(), null, 'register.log');
```

in Both Store Views I get:

```
    Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /html/dev/lib/Zend/Debug.php, line 108

Trace:
#0 /html/dev/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(107): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://dev.fash...', 302)
#2 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(750): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://dev.fash...')
#3 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(279): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirectError('http://dev.fash...')
#4 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->createPostAction()
#5 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('createpost')
#6 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /html/dev/index.php(128): Mage::run('site2', 'website')
#10 {main}
```

and in the log file I get:

First line is the shop that fails, the second in the view that works:

```
2014-05-20T07:41:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2014-05-20T07:43:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
```

And I also get this:

```
2014-05-20T07:50:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 268
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, I've changed the code to this:

```
    public function createPostAction()
{

    Mage::log($this->getRequest()->isPost(), null, 'register.log');

    Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getParams(), null, 'register.log');

    /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
```

Now this outputs the following for the view that does not work:

```
2014-05-20T09:20:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
2014-05-20T09:20:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)
```

so they are both empty!

And this is what I get for the view that does work:

```
2014-05-20T09:21:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2014-05-20T09:21:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [success_url] => 
    [error_url] => 
    [prefix] => Frau
    [firstname] => dqedqw
    [lastname] => dqwdqwdqw
    [email] => qwdqwdqwd@qwdqwd.de
    [password] => testtest
    [confirmation] => testtest
)
```

I really can not see why this is. I've compared the template and html output files of the registration form, which are the same.

Comment: would you be able to override Magento's AccountController's action 'createPost()' and debug what could be wrong?

Comment: How do I do that? The thing is, I presume it has to be theme based error as we have 2 themes on the same core, one works, the other does not.

Comment: presumably yes, but there could be something wrong in your 2nd store's setup in the backend.

Comment: Try to compare how `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` looks like in both cases in the `createPostAction` method in the AccountController. Maybe something is different. Also you can try reverting to the default theme for test purposes.

Comment: Ok, i've set the theme to default for that storeview and the same happens (in the dev version, not the link above), so maybe it isn't directly related to the theme.

Comment: @ Marius: Could you briefly explain how I do that, please?

Comment: I've added some edits to the first post in regards to debugging. Can anyone help me from here?

Comment: Looks like in the first case you don't send the values through post. Check the form method. It may be 'get' or it may be missing.

Comment: in the system log i get: 2014-05-20T07:50:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given  in /html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 268

Comment: I've reverted to the default theme, the template form method is: `<form id="form-validate" method="post" action="http://dev.domain.com/customer/account/createpost/">`

Comment: Considering this is most likely to be a config issue as the default theme also does not work for this store view, how would this issue be possible at all from a wrong db value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, the issue wasn't settings nor theme based, but my hosts fault.

Since we use SSL with Varnish we have the option to direct the ssl IP to varnish, which I have disabled in the admin panel since we are still testing a varnish config.

However, Mittwald - our host which has so far cost us a lot of time and money and I can thus not recommend them - seem to have their admin panel settings not in working order.

So the SSL was still running via varnish even though it shouldn't as the SSL wasn't pointed to the varnish cache according to their settings page when it clearly was.

I had to overwrite the .vcl file with a blank to get it to work.

Thank you all for your help!